# Xamarin - Expander inside ListView not showing properly on iOs

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, size, expander

Hello Im trying to use a Xamarin Toolkit Expander in a ViewCell of a ListView.
On android works as expected without any problem but on iOs looks like the ViewCell is not changing its size and the content of the expander is not usable.

[image: Expander before expanding]
[image: Expander after expanding (the buttons are not clickable)]

It has a strange behaviour because if I scroll up enough to hide the header looks like the cell resizes itself and the content works fine but when clicking again the header the content hides but the cell keeps on the same size

[image: After scrolling up the size changes]
[image: But when collapsing the content the size keeps the same]

Here is the xaml code

```xml
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame Margin="0,10,0,0" Padding="0">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="0">
                            <BoxView BackgroundColor="#FF9A31" HeightRequest="15" WidthRequest="15"/>
                            <behaviors:Expander Margin="10,0,10,0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="Expander">
                                <behaviors:Expander.Header>

                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding NombreCliente}" FontSize="25" TextColor="Gray"/>


                                        <Image Source="adultos.png" HeightRequest="20" Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                            <Image.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Image"
                                                     Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type behaviors:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                                                     Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="IsVisible"
                                                    Value="False" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Image.Triggers>
                                        </Image>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding PaxAdultos}" x:Name="AdultsHeaderText" FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Gray">
                                            <Label.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                                                     Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type behaviors:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                                                     Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="IsVisible"
                                                    Value="False" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Label.Triggers>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Image Source="ninos.png" HeightRequest="20">
                                            <Image.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Image"
                                                     Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type behaviors:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                                                     Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="IsVisible"
                                                    Value="False" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Image.Triggers>
                                        </Image>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding PaxNinos}" x:Name="NinosHeaderText" FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Gray">
                                            <Label.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                                                     Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type behaviors:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                                                     Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="IsVisible"
                                                    Value="False" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Label.Triggers>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Image Source="bebe.png" HeightRequest="20">
                                            <Image.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Image"
                                                     Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type behaviors:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                                                     Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="IsVisible"
                                                    Value="False" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Image.Triggers>
                                        </Image>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding PaxBebes}" x:Name="BebesHeaderText" FontSize="20" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Gray">
                                            <Label.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label"
                                                     Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type behaviors:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                                                     Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="IsVisible"
                                                    Value="False" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Label.Triggers>
                                        </Label>
                                        <Image HeightRequest="20" Source="arrow_down.png" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                            <Image.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Image"
                                                     Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type behaviors:Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                                                     Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Source"
                                                    Value="arrow_up.png" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Image.Triggers>
                                        </Image>
                                    </StackLayout>


                                </behaviors:Expander.Header>
                                <behaviors:Expander.Content>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0,10">
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image Source="adultos.png" HeightRequest="25" Margin="30,0,0,0" />
                                            <ImageButton Source="menos.png" WidthRequest="20" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="44,0" x:Name="menosAdultos" Clicked="OnLessAdults" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                            <Label x:Name="nAdultsText" Text="{Binding PaxAdultos}" FontSize="20" TextColor="Gray" />
                                            <ImageButton Source="mas.png" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="15" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="44,0" x:Name="masAdultos" Clicked="OnMoreAdults" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                            <Image Source="ninos.png" HeightRequest="25" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
                                            <ImageButton Source="menos.png" WidthRequest="20"  BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="44,0" x:Name="menosNinos" Clicked="OnLessKids" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                            <Label x:Name="nKidsText" Text="{Binding PaxNinos}" FontSize="20" TextColor="Gray"/>
                                            <ImageButton Source="mas.png" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="15" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="44,0" x:Name="masNinos" Clicked="OnMoreKids" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                            <Image Source="bebe.png" HeightRequest="25" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
                                            <ImageButton Source="menos.png" WidthRequest="20" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="44,0" x:Name="menosBebes" Clicked="OnLessBabies" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                            <Label x:Name="nBabiesText" Text="{Binding PaxBebes}" FontSize="20" TextColor="Gray"/>
                                            <ImageButton Source="mas.png" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="15" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="44,0" x:Name="masBebes" Clicked="OnMoreBabies" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <Button x:Name="ConfirmarButton" FontSize="12" Text="CONFIRMAR CLIENTE" HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="10,0" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Black" Margin="0,10,0,0" Clicked="ConfirmarButton_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </behaviors:Expander.Content>
                            </behaviors:Expander>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
```

Isn't it weird that on android works withou any problem but on iOs i am getting this weird behaviour?

Comment: Just spitballing. Are you using HasUnevenRows = true on the list view? Also, you can force the cell size to update on some event. See the [Xamarin docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#resize-rows-at-runtime) for an example.

Comment: Yes, I am using HasUnevenRows = true and its not working...
I will give it a look to that event u are refering and if I can finally make it work I'll leave here

Comment: You should add ForceUpdateSizeCommand property to Expander control,please refer to:https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/420